# Pouchdb document structure

Tags: pouchdb, nosql

I create a simple application to test how pouchdb work. I create a simple form to add item. Normally on RDBMS every new item is consider as a new row of data.

In pouchdb, if i consider every new item as a new document, is it appropriate?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As described in [the PouchDB guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html), there are some rough equivalences between PouchDB and relational SQL databases, but it's not a perfect correspondence. You may want to look into [relational-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch) if you want relational data, and it also looks like you would benefit from [the PouchDB Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pouchdb-inspector/hbhhpaojmpfimakffndmpmpndcmonkfa/reviews) Chrome extension, since the IndexedDB view is very fine-grained and really shows you how PouchDB works under the hood.